# Android Async Task on Splashscreen

Tags: android, android-asynctask

I'm working on a project. The people who want this app don't want the smartphones to acces the database. So they place xml files online. When the application is first installed I read the xml's in a local sqlite database so they can acces the data offline.

Now the xml files are loaded into the sqlite. It does not take long time to load the xml files, but long enough to place it in een async task. Now I don't know if it's smart to make a splashscreen and run the xml parsing in a async task. Or if I need to do this on an other time?

Does anyone have a solution for this?

Thanks!

Comment: Is the application functional without the data? If *not* it should probably be an `AsyncTask` and a progress update/splash on the screen when doing your initial preparations.

Comment: No you need the data. So the first time I will load the data in a asynctask on the splash. And give the user feedback with a progressbar.. Thanks for the fast reply!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, of course any operations containing network and database lookups should be done in a separate thread (using `AsyncTask` is a good idea). Then, there are two ways to implement your logic:

1. If your users can do nothing with your application before the data is fetched and placed into DB, you probably should show some kind of `ProgressDialog` telling your users that your application is preparing itself for the work.
2. If there are other options that don't require the data from the Internet, you must run the data fetching operation completely in background, letting your users interact with the application.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Would it be a good idea if I place the xml files on the application. So when they don't have internet acces I can parse the xml files. (and let them know they have a old version of the db) But they can use the app. The moment they have acces to the internet I check for an update?

Comment: And with number 1 you mean also sort of splash with progressbar/dialog?

Comment: @user1110599, If your application's logic allows it - sure you can. Also I'd recommend you implement a Service and a Broadcast Receiver to listen for connectivity info. When your user connects to network, the Service can download data in background making your application ready to go when users open it.

Comment: @user1110599, Yes, a ProgressDialog is one of the best practices in this situation.

Comment: I have another solution. I've made an sqlite db and will install it with the application. Now I've done some research and if I understand the way it works correct you need to copy the data into a database? As the following link shows: [link](http://www.reigndesign.com/blog/using-your-own-sqlite-database-in-android-applications/)

Comment: But can't you just copy the db file into the /data/dat/<app/databases directory and acces it?

Comment: @user1110599, Sorry, not sure about that question, you need to try it.

Answer (score 0):

I think it depends on how would you deal with an error, say, your server is down, or something is wrong with user's internet connection. Splashscreen is fine for loading up resources that are required to show the activity itself, but I don't think it's a good idea to keep user waiting on it running `AsyncTask`s in background, it could make your application look slow => bad user experience.

Comment: That's actually what I'm afraid of. But the application does not work without the data. So I need to make a choice. At the moment I don't see another solution then the splash. How would you take this problem down?

Comment: I think you should talk to people who `want the app`, how do they feel about not showing anything in their app if there's no connection. Would they want you to cache the last xml you got? You would only have to pull a newer version and update your UI. Anyhow, it's not a good idead to be stuck in a splashcreen, so don't do that.